# Flipping a Video Horizontally in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I have a video such that when I play it in full view and flip the simulator horizontally the video would not flip. How can I make the video flip according to the iPhone's accelerometer?

Here is the code for the video if it helps:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MainPageMovie" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(115.0, 156.0, 200.0, 150.0);
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    [theMovie play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MPMoviePlayerController view is added as a subview to another view controller's view. In that parent view controller, have you overridden shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method?
If you are just looking for landscape (horizontal) rotation, you can have your code as below:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Comment: `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`

Comment: Vera No this application is a primitive one and I have not added rotation for any of the views. All the views are vertical. I just want to rotate the video when it is in full view. Can this be done??

Comment: Problem solved for the video :) I just added (return YES;) to the code.
But now the problem is that all the other views rotate when I rotate the simulator. I did not add landscape views for the other views. How can I allow the rotation for the video ONLY?

Comment: EDIT: none of the other views rotate except for the view which I added the rotation code to (the view which the video is in). My question now is, how can allow rotation ONLY to the video when it is in full screen view?

Answer (score 0):

In order to rotate specific subviews of the larger view controller view, (which in your situation would be the case with only rotating the video), you'd have to do `CGAffineTransform`s. This would allow you to resize a view, rotate it, etc. AFAIK, this is probably the best route to go for rotating a single view.

However, you may want to research more into `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421061/mpmovieplayercontroller-only-rotate-on-fullscreen), it seems to address your problem.