# MPMoviePlayerController only rotate on fullscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

I have a table view that contains an instance of MPMoviePlayerController as the table header and when the user presses my custom overlay button, the video expands to full screen. The aspect ratio of the video is such that in portrait mode it is very small, and I imagine most users will rotate to landscape.

The problem is that I want to allow rotation when the video is full screen but not when it exits. My underlying table does not support landscape. Is there a way to support rotation only when full screen? I thought this would be a standard component of MPMoviePlayerController.

I'm using SDK 5.0, but it was originally built with 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subclassing the <s>`MPMoviePlayerController`</s> `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class, and overriding the method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (!self.fullscreen) {
        return UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but maybe I'll give it a shot now. If that doesn't work, I'm going to try using MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is not a UIViewController - did this actually work for you when trying?

Comment: @Till You're right, my mistake. I was referring to the MPMoviePlayerViewController. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your responses. I ended up using an MPMoviePlayerVIEWController to present a modal view, and it now handles rotation on its own.